# How to map macro variables in SAS with existing variable in the table?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a table named as **report**, and there is a variable called `ord` which takes values 1,2,3...15. I have generated global macro variables `&n1`, `&n2`, `&n3`.... `&n15` which are all numeric.

I wish to add another column `value` into the table **report**, which takes value of corresponding macro variables.

For example, `%SYSEVALF(&n1)` = 10, `%SYSEVALF(&n13)` = 22 , `%SYSEVALF(&n10)` = 8

`id ord value
1  1    10
2  13   22
3  10   8`

....

I know there are many ways to solve it, however, I want to accopmlish it through just a few lines of code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `SYMGETN()` function.

```
value = symgetn(cats('n',ord));
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I want!